# Can't dual boot Win 10 and XP

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, multi-boot

I can't install Windows XP. IF I try, at the first moment, the PC will reboot and boot to Windows 10 (default). How do I install WIn XP without the PC self-rebooting? IF I do it in VMware, I get a drive error.

Comment: I can almost guarantee the reason Windows 10 and Windows XP won't get along, is due to the fact Windows 10 was installed on a GPT disk which means UEFI, and Windows XP has zero support for it.  Clearly Windows 10 still supports MBR and Legacy boot but you have to go out of your way to do that.

Comment: @Ramhound they are both running on a legacy BIOS PC.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I'd run XP in a VM these days - that way every time it gets compromised you can just replace the VM from a backup.

XP probably has no drivers for your hardware anyway, so will struggle to even run on actual hardware.

Comment: I tried it on a VM, and I got a drive error

Comment: That's a tad vague.

Comment: I totally agree with @Tetsujin.  Perhaps you need to pursue the cause of the drive error. :)  That isn't normal.  VirtualBox?  VMWare?  Hyper-V?   If you truly want XP.. that can be done.. but is pointless with how good virtualization has  become.  What was the actual error? etc etc

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas The operation on file "\\.\PhysicalDrive1" failed.

If the file resides on a remote file system, make sure that the network connection and the server where this disk resides are functioning properly. If the file resides on removable media, reattach the media.

Comment: @s7382 don't bother running XP from an existing physical disk. If you need it then create a new vitual disk, install it from scratch and run it from there.

Comment: @Mokubai If I start from scratch, it says the same thing but instead of "PhysicalDrive1" it says "Windows XP.vmdk".